# Finding the angle a vector makes over variable axes

Tags: c, cocos2d-iphone, geometry, transformation, trigonometry

The typical way to find the angle a vector makes from the *x* axis (assuming the *x* axis runs left to right, and the *y* axis runs bottom to top) is:

```
double vector_angle = atan2( y , x )
```

However, I want my axes to have their origin at a point on a circle so that the *x* axis runs from the point on the edge of the circle through the centre of the circle, and the *y* axis runs tangent to the circle at that point (which would thus be perpendicular to the *x* axis).

Assumedly the code would still be the same, but now adjusted by a distance *k* and an angle *theta*, perhaps:

```
double y_position = ( y + k ) * theta;
double x_position = ( x + k ) * theta;
double vector_angle = atan2( y_position, x_position );
```

But I'm not sure about this. This is a generalised problem for a touch-based application where I would like to have a general way to move a sprite (in cocos2d) using swipe motions which is always a constant distance from the center of a circle.

[image]

Here, *B* is the origin of the vector which could be transformed by a rotation *theta*. For example, if we transformed the circle and point *B* by 90 degrees, *B* would be at (4, 0) and the line *B*->*A* would be along the axis at 4 (y = 4). I would like to get the angle in node-space of point *B*, when under transform.

Comment: The arctangent gives you the angle of the vector only if the vector's origin is (0,0). Where does the vector originate in your other coordinates? The center of the circle? Could you include a sketch of a sample vector to explain a little better?

Comment: Excuse me, the vector originates at the point on the circle where my new axes would be coming from. The point on the circle where the tangent is formed.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Based on the new paragraph, it sounds like your vector is always running from a point on the circle to its center. Under your altered coordinate system, this is always one branch of the _x_ axis, so the angle is always either 0˚ or 180˚. Unless you want the angle in the _original_ coordinate system? But if that's true, your original procedure works -- just use `atan2()`.

Comment: Slight error, it runs from the point on the circle along the tangent. So it would be 90 or 270.

Comment: @SamP: SOunds like you found your solution. If so, feel free to answer your own question so that we can get it out of the “unanswered” queue and so that others can benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arctan returns the correct angle for the vector where the "x axis" is the line perpendicular to your tangent.